# Can't downgrade to the version I just upgraded from

Tags: apt, downgrade

This morning a regular software update brought in an update to Firefox that broke some important functionality in an app I run on top of it (with `firefox -app`).  I checked my upgrade history and found that the previous version of Firefox was `52.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1`, installed on April 1.  So I tried:

```
~$ sudo aptitude install firefox=52.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
Unable to find a version "52.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1" for the package "firefox"
```

And then just:

```
~$ sudo aptitude install firefox=52.0.2
Unable to find a version "52.0.2" for the package "firefox"
```

Is a package version less than a month old really out of reach, or is there some way to get it?

Comment: Link to the .deb package you're looking for: https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/firefox-esr/+build/15059457/+files/firefox-esr_52.9.0esr-1~14.04.york0_amd64.deb

Comment: Download old builds of Firefox here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/ubuntuzilla/files/mozilla/apt/pool/main/f/firefox-mozilla-build/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run:

```
aptitude versions ^firefox$
```

You will get:

```
pi  45.0.2+build1-0ubuntu1         codename                              500 
id  53.0+build6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1   codename-security,code-name-updates   500
```

You can also use something like:

```
apt list -a firefox
```

To get available version for install.

```
Listing... Done
firefox/release-updates,release-security,now 53.0+build6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 amd64 [installed]
firefox/release 45.0.2+build1-0ubuntu1 amd64
```

The idea is that in `release-updates` only the last version of a software is available for installation.

You can either install a software from `release` which is the start point and frozen (in our case is 45.0.2), or from `release-updates`/`security` which last version (53.0) is there.

If you want to install Firefox 52, you can download it from [here](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/firefox/firefox_52.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb), or have access to all versions from [here](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/firefox/).

You can also check the cache:

```
ls -l /var/cache/apt/archives/firefox*
```

If you didn't used something like `apt autoclean` or `apt clean` there should be at least previous version of firefox `deb` package:

```
/var/cache/apt/archives/firefox_52.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/firefox_53.0+build6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb
```

Then first unistall the current version of firefox and after that use `dpkg` or `gdebi` to install the downloaded `deb` file:

```
sudo dpkg -i firefox-version.deb
```

or

```
sudo gdebi firefox-version.deb
```

---

Remember that you can always use `apt-mark hold` to prevent a package from updating:

```
sudo apt-mark hold firefox
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run the following to see the available versions of firefox:

```
apt-cache showpkg firefox
```

Then install an older version by running

```
sudo apt-get install firefox=version
```

For example, when I run the first command, I get the following output:

```
Package: firefox
Versions: 
53.0+build6-0ubuntu0.17.04.1 (/var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_zesty-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages) (/var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_zesty-security_main_binary-amd64_Packages) (/var/lib/dpkg/status)
 Description Language: 
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_zesty_main_binary-amd64_Packages
                  MD5: 46b619f510631c4693dc09c1a3778a55
 Description Language: 
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_zesty_main_binary-i386_Packages
                  MD5: 46b619f510631c4693dc09c1a3778a55
 Description Language: en
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_zesty_main_i18n_Translation-en
                  MD5: 46b619f510631c4693dc09c1a3778a55
 Description Language: 
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_zesty-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages
                  MD5: 46b619f510631c4693dc09c1a3778a55
 Description Language: 
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_zesty-updates_main_binary-i386_Packages
                  MD5: 46b619f510631c4693dc09c1a3778a55

50.1.0+build2-0ubuntu1 (/var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_zesty_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
 Description Language: 
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_zesty_main_binary-amd64_Packages
                  MD5: 46b619f510631c4693dc09c1a3778a55
 Description Language: 
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_zesty_main_binary-i386_Packages
                  MD5: 46b619f510631c4693dc09c1a3778a55
 Description Language: en
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_zesty_main_i18n_Translation-en
                  MD5: 46b619f510631c4693dc09c1a3778a55
 Description Language: 
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_zesty-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages
                  MD5: 46b619f510631c4693dc09c1a3778a55
 Description Language: 
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_zesty-updates_main_binary-i386_Packages
                  MD5: 46b619f510631c4693dc09c1a3778a55
```

... and a bunch of other stuff about dependencies.

So I can downgrade firefox using:

```
sudo apt-get install firefox=50.1.0+build2-0ubuntu1
```